# setIcon(ic_menu_more) doesn't have effect

Tags: android, resources, menuitem

Sample code from the book:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(0, Menu.FIRST, 0, "Go");

    menuItem.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_more);    // doesn't work

    return true;
}
```

When I press Menu button in Android emulator, "Go" option is shown in the bottom of the screen, but without any icon - both if setIcon called or not. What is wrong?

Comment: which android version is on your emulator ?

Comment: @Selvin - Android 4.0, API level 14.

Comment: this code works as expected on my emulator, try to clean and rebuild application ... edit: if this will not help ... make new avd  :)

Comment: i think that that with normal theme there is no icons in menu on ICS, but if you choose NoActionBar or NoTitleBar theme (or feature from code) menu will appear in the old manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this [tuto](http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/building-a-menu-for-your-android-v10-r1-app/) . hope it helps

**EDIT :** 
 try this :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        SubMenu m = menu.addSubMenu(0, 1000, 0, "Go");
        m.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the answer to my question in this link. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Houcine - the same result, no icon.

Comment: it's strange, because the same method that i've used in a project Android 1.6, and it works ,, try to change the sdk version to 1.6 and retry

Comment: OK, this is not critical issue.